# javadoc: referring to concepts in the class header?

Tags: javadoc

I have an interface `IFoo` (not the real name) I'm trying to write Javadoc for -- this is a package that's exposed to Rhino/Jython scripting via JSR223 and this one interface is the only one exposed.

It has numerous methods that are fairly simple. Many of them are beans but some are not.

```
public void setBar(double x);
public double getBar();
public void setBigQuux(int n);
public int getBigQuux();
public void setLittleQuux(int n);
public int getLittleQuux();
public void clearQuuxes();
```

My question is, many of these methods form into natural groups. One way to do this, which seems like the one Sun has chosen (I've looked at some of the Swing classes), is to choose one method of each group and put most of the relevant information in its javadoc, then link the others with `@see` tags. Another approach (which seems like a better way to me) to document groups of closely-related methods, is to put a section into the class Javadoc header, and then to put a brief summary into the method headers but refer to the header, but I'm not sure how to do this:

```
/**
 * Foo
 * <p>
 * Quuxes: these are magic knobs that control quux content. A foo has a big quux
 * and a little quux. (etc) (I want to link here from the quux-related methods)
 */
interface IFoo    
{
  /**
   * Sets the big quux
   * @param n new value
   * @see ???? how to refer to the quux section of the class header?
   */
  public void setBigQuux(int n);
  /**
   * Gets the big quux
   * @return big quux 
   * @see ???? how to refer to the quux section of the class header?
   */
  public int getBigQuux();
  /* etc */
}
```

Can anybody help me out, or explain why this is a bad idea?

Answer (score 1):

Aha, got it working, using `<a name="abcd">`/`<a href="#abcd">` tag pairs in the header and in the `@see` line. The reference for this syntax is in the [javadoc reference for `@see`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#see).

```
/**
 * Foo
 * <p>
 * <a name="quuxes">Quuxes</a>:
 * these are magic knobs that control quux content. A foo has a big quux
 * and a little quux. (etc) (I want to link here from the quux-related methods)
 */
interface IFoo    
{
  /**
   * Sets the big quux
   * @param n new value
   * @see <a href="#quuxes">quuxes</a>
   * @see #getBigQuux
   */
  public void setBigQuux(int n);
  /**
   * Gets the big quux
   * @return big quux 
   * @see <a href="#quuxes">quuxes</a>
   * @see #setBigQuux
   */
  public int getBigQuux();
  /* etc */
}
```